# Making code duplication to refresh the gridview in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, database, gridview

I am trying to update the gridview after updating some data. Here is my code:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection();
    con.ConnectionString = University.GetConnectionString();
    con.Open();
    string query = "select [ID],[Name],[Surname],[level] from StudentTable order by ID";
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, con);
    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    da.Fill(dt);
    studentLevel.DataSource = dt;
    studentLevel.DataBind();
    con.Close();
}
protected void studentLevel_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
{
    int row = -1;
    int.TryParse(e.CommandArgument as string, out row);

    GridViewRow gdrow = studentLevel.Rows[row];
    DataRow dr = ((DataTable)studentLevel.DataSource).Rows[gdrow.DataItemIndex];

    string id = dr["ID"].ToString();
    Student student = new Student(Convert.ToInt32(id), "", "", "", "", "", "", "");
    if (e.CommandName == "Undergraduate")
        student.setLevelRole(new UnderGraduateStudent());
    else if (e.CommandName == "Graduate")
        student.setLevelRole(new GraduateStudent());
    student.writeLevelRole(id);

    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection();     //HERE IS DUPLICATION
                                                 //refresh the gridview on the page
    con.ConnectionString = University.GetConnectionString();
    con.Open();
    string query = "select [ID],[Name],[Surname],[level] from StudentTable order by ID";
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, con);  
    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    da.Fill(dt);
    studentLevel.DataSource = dt;
    studentLevel.DataBind();
    con.Close();
}
```

The problem is, if i do not write the last 12 lines of the code, which is the same code as page_load method, the gridview does not refresh itself on the page. Waht can i do to avoid this?

Thanks

Comment: Extract it to separate method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should provide a method that loads the data and databinds the `GridView`, for example `DataBindGrid`:

```
private void DataBindGrid()
{
    using(var con = new SqlConnection(University.GetConnectionString()))
    {
        con.Open();
        string query = "select [ID],[Name],[Surname],[level] from StudentTable order by ID";
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, con);
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        da.Fill(dt);
        studentLevel.DataSource = dt;
        studentLevel.DataBind();
    }
}
```

Then you can call it from wherever you need. If you want to change something you have only one place to maintain which is less error-prone.

Note that you should databind the GridView only `if(!IsPostBack)` if you use `ViewState`(default):

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(!IsPostback))
        DataBindGridView();
}
```

and in `RowCommand`

```
protected void studentLevel_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
{
   // ... update student ... then
   DataBindGridView();
}
```